# Can't reach server endpoints when running Docker Compose Python Interpreter

Tags: networking, docker-compose, pycharm, uvicorn

I have a small setup for a few services inside a `docker-compose.yaml`. For brevity, this is the service which is intended as the main API to use other services:

```yaml
services:

  fprint-api:
    container_name: fprint-api-v2
    image: "fprint-api:v0.0.1"
    depends_on:
      - fprint-svc

    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

    build:
      context: ../.
      dockerfile: docker/Dockerfile.fprint-api

  # ...
```

`fprint-api` has a simple health-check endpoint like so:

```py
@app.get("/health")
def health():
    return "API OK"
```

If I just run `docker-compose up`  on this, or use the Docker Compose run-configuration in PyCharm, everything works and I am able to make a GET request to http://localhost:8000.

However, if I use a remote python interpreter on said `docker-compse.yaml` and the `fprint-api` service, I can't reach this endpoint anymore. The system spins up, but the endpoint is not accessible and as such I am unable to debug my endpoints.

I am not sure what I'm missing here exactly.

### Remote Interpreter Configuration

[image]

### Run-Configuration for the `fprint-api` Service

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, that's an easy one.

`uvicorn` needs the `--host` flag set to `0.0.0.0` in order to be able to access the URL via the hostname `localhost`:

[image]